What engine can I swap into my 2013 Subaru Impreza sport harchback that will make significantly more power than the stock engine
I’m trying to figure out what engine I can put into my car that would give me around 250+hp minimum, the higher the better of course. I don’t know if it has to be a Subaru engine that’s the issue I’m trying to figure out. Like could I hypothetically put a 2jz in? I know little to nothing about these things

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

When it comes to engine swap, there is always a WAY cheaper option - just get a factory-built more powerful car.

No, a 2JZ isn't goin to fit in there. It's about 2x as long as the original engine which went in there .. unless you want it in your lap or hanging out the front end of your Impreza.
Your best bet is to get a different engine which WILL fit in there ... while I'm not an expert on the Subaru, the most common swap is to put another, more powerful, Subaru engine in there in it's place. If yours is the stock engine, more than likely it's the 2.0L 4-cylinder engine which produces 148hp stock. Luckily for you Subaru has done two things in your favor. Your same vehicle comes in a WRX and WRX STI model (each with a different engine). These engines put out 265hp and 305hp, respectively. Both are also 4-cylinder engines. The second thing Subaru did is make it so these engines are fairly interchangeable, meaning bolt patterns and mounting positions should be pretty much the same. Subarus are called the "Lego" car, because a lot of things you can bolt right up without issue one to another.
With this in mind, your best "swap" engine would most likely be one of these two engines. The downside comes is you pretty much have to find a donor car to make it happen. These donor cars are HIGHLY sought after so they come at a price. There are a lot of people out there trying to do the same swap as what I'm describing, so they are in demand. This is, however, going to be the easiest route for you to go to get better power out of your Impreza with the least amount of angst.

Thank you this was extremely in depth and helpful I appreciate your time!!

@hsfin - If this answers your question, please feel free to select the checkmark to the left of the answer and below the voting arrows to mark it as such.
